# How to find file names matching a pattern and copying those in unix?

Tags: unix

I want to find list of files starting with `All_Responses_11367` and copy those files to another directory. For example  for each day I have 40 files and need to copy for last 80 days files:

```
All_Responses_11367_8_20_2013.txt
All_Responses_11368_8_20_2013.txt
All_Responses_11369_8_20_2013.txt
All_Responses_11367_8_21_2013.txt
All_Responses_11368_8_21_2013.txt
All_Responses_11369_8_21_2013.txt
All_Responses_11367_8_22_2013.txt
All_Responses_11368_8_22_2013.txt
All_Responses_11369_8_22_2013.txt
```

I would like to copy one same files for all dates at a time.

```
All_Responses_11367_8_20_2013.txt
All_Responses_11367_8_21_2013.txt
All_Responses_11367_8_22_2013.txt
```

I want only last 77 date files by file name, which consists of a date.I want those last 77 days files by file name and not the file generated date. How can I achieve this?

Comment: All files are in one directory?

Answer (score 1):

This find command should give all file starting with `All_Responses_11367*` in current directory modified/created in last 77 days:

```
find . -name "All_Responses_11367*" -maxdepth 1 -type f -mtime -77 -exec cp '{}' dest \;
```

Change `dest` to some other directory where you want to copy these files.